# Selecting certain data to show in console from an Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, parsing

I have a JSON file with the structure

```json
{
    "Search": {
        "CarInfo": [
            {
                "name": "Focus",
                "price": 107.25,
                "supplier": "Ford",
                "rating": 5.4
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've put this into an array after parsing, and now I want to print the array so that it just shows name and price, for example, of all the cars (20+ cars in my JSON).
So far, I can only get it to print the full pointer of the array, so the full (name,price,supplier & rating).

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {         
    System.out.println(list.get(i));                
}
```

I've tried to use `contains("name")`, and that won't work. Just wondering if there is a way around this to just print out what I want, or if there is a different way and I've approached this wrong.

Comment: What type is `list` specifically, what does `list.get(i)` return?

Comment: If you want to print the content of an array, use `Arrays.toString`, so maybe  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.get(i)));` will do the trick assuming you have an `List<SomeArray[]>`.

Comment: list is and ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>

And it returns all the items in teh array

{"name": "Focus","price": 107.25,"supplier": "Ford","rating": 5.4}
then the next ones along the array.

Comment: Could i put an Array into the Array so the second array contains the values of price,name,rating,supplier inside the first array. so i can point to that and print it out